# How to Edit the Imported Word Document using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, docx, python-docx, doc

I do have a word document and I want to edit it. Here is the part of the document.
[Part of Word Document]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5JGO.jpg

I could upload it into jupyter notebook using **python-docx**.

I can access to each line by

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('StudentReport.docx')
len(doc.paragraphs)
output- 31

print(doc.paragraphs[7].text)
output- 98% of Student have some access
```

So I just want to change that 98% to 85%.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add the code you wrote and explain better the desired output

Comment: I edit the question. I just want to know, how those lines could edit and put those in the same place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just plainly set it as:

```
doc.paragraphs[7].text = '85% of Student have some access'
```

In case you want to be teeny tiny bit more fancy about it:

```
doc.paragraphs[7].text = doc.paragraphs[7].text.replace('98%','85%')
```